# How to add style to React Element if it's created this way?

Tags: reactjs

```
var MyElement = React.createClass({displayName: "FormatParagraph",
    render: function () {
        return (
            React.createElement("p", null, this.props.paragraph)
            );
    }
});
```

How can I add a style object to this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The second parameter to `createElement` is a hash of attributes where the key is the attribute name and the value is the attribute value. The `style` attribute takes a hash of style names to values. So, for example:

```
React.createElement("p", {style: {color: "red", backgroundColor: "blue"}}, this.props.paragraph)
```

Comment: how to add multiple styles?

Comment: @RamiSalim what do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

```
React.createElement("p", {id : 'div1', className : 'news'}, this.props.paragraph)
```

This way you can use CSS specified in `App.css` inside in an `id/class`.