# Specify position of elements, React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am new to JS world and stuck with this, probably, simple problem:
I want to specify position of the element that will be added to another element and I want to set position in the app, but not in .css.

Now I have

```
var obj = DOM.div({className: 'testPlace'},
             React.createElement("a", {id: 'testPlace'},".")
         );
```

and in .css

```
div.testPlace {  position: absolute;
                    right: 50px;
                    bottom: 100px;
                }
```

I want to set parameters for right and bottom inside of the app, not in .css.
How can I do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In ReactJS, you can set this while creating the element, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281944/how-to-add-style-to-react-element-if-its-created-this-way):

It would be:

```
React.createElement("a", {style: {position: "absolute", right: "50px", bottom: "100px"}}, {id: 'testPlace'},".")
```

In plain Javascript, you can set the properties as:

```
element.style.right = "50px";

element.style.bottom = "100px";
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.