# How to use style tag in ReactJS while using non-JSX syntax?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need a quick help. I am using ReactJS with non-JSX syntax because I feel more comfortable using it than JSX

I can easily create a div , but I don't know how to include the style tag like we do in pure html ; for example : `<div class="some-name-here" style="some-style-here"......</div>`

Here is the code :

```
var DOMstyle = {
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  width : 100
};


let Header = class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      React.createElement('div', {className : 'header'}, "hello",
      )
    );
  }
};
```

I'm trying to include the DOMstyle into this div so browser will see something like `<div class="some-name-here" style="some-style-here"......</div>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281944/how-to-add-style-to-react-element-if-its-created-this-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass define pass in custom style from javascript to the style property in the object you pass into React.createElement.

```js
const DOMstyle = {
  borderTop: '2px solid blue',
  width : '100%',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
}

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', {className: 'header', style : DOMstyle}, "hello");
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.header {
  font-family: 'arial';
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The result is something like

```
<div class="header" style="font-family: 'arial';color:#fff;">Hello</div>
```

Comment: This works fine to me. Thanks for the quick and accurate answer.

Comment: quick question : How to specify units in DOMstyle ; like width : 100% for example ?

Comment: any idea how to include multiple arguments like : border-top: 1px , solid , red ; for example ?

Comment: @coco like this: `const DOMstyle = {
  width : '100%',
  backgroundColor: 'red', borderTop: '1px solid red'
}` put all the values inside `''` space separated, it will work.